Why are the spectra of large atomic nuclei described by random matrix theory?
I have seen in many references on random matrix theory that it was historically applied to study the spectra of atomic nuclei. However I'm confused about how this randomness appears - the atomic Hamiltonian is not random and should not exhibit fluctuations (i.e., if I scatter off an atom at fixed energy the resulting cross section should be repeatable).
So my question is, since there is no disorder or randomness in the problem, why is RMT relevant? One answer I considered is that what we are really doing is making a typicality statement, i.e., perhaps "most" matrices have eigenvalue statistics that look like those of the ensemble, so there is a kind of self-averaging. But I haven't seen the problem discussed this way and I'm worried that I am making a conceptual mistake.
Edit: I've been asked for examples of references. Here are some:
This review has an extended discussion of RMT beginning on page 8 which mentions the application of RMT to atomic nuclei.
This review quickly gets into the discussion of scattering on Uranium nuclei, but again I am confused about why RMT works so well for this specific, seemingly non-random system.

Please give at least one explicit reference: title, author(s), chapter/section, page number, and if possible a link.

I've added two examples to the question, thanks for your suggestion.
